# How can I add record when user clicks on Add Rec button

Tags: angular, html, css

```js
// This is my Component.ts
// How can i add a new row for this table with new Values.

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-uom',
  templateUrl: './uom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uom.component.css']
})

export class UomComponent implements OnInit {
  itemIdVal: '';
  itemDescVal = '';
  itemClassval = '';
  itemSubClassVal = '';
  show: boolean;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
addRec() {
 // alert(this.itemIdVal + '|| ' + this.itemDescVal + '|| ' + this.itemClassval + '|| ' + this.itemSubClassVal);
}
}
```

```html
<!--This is my Component.html -->
<table style="width:100%;"> 
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Item ID" [(ngModel)] = "itemIdVal"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Item Description" [(ngModel)]="itemDescVal"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" placeholder=" Please Enter Classification" [(ngModel)]="itemClassval"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Sub-Class" [(ngModel)]="itemSubClassVal"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="25">
 <th width="25%">Item ID</th>
 <th width="25%">Item Description</th>
 <th width="25%">Item Classification</th>
 <th>Item Sub-Classification <span class="buttons"><a  (click)="addRec()"><span>Add Record</span></a></span></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>{{itemIdVal}}</td>
 <td>{{itemDescVal}}</td>
 <td>{{itemClassval}}</td>
 <td>{{itemSubClassVal}}</td>
 </tr>  
</thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by add record? Do you want to add a new row or add the row data to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

For you four variables, which you defined in your `uom.component.ts`, you have added four `input`-fields which `[(ngModel)]`. With `[(ngModel)]` you have add two-way data binding for your variables. That means, that if add some content by your `input`-field, you will have the same content in your variables. Read more about two-way data binding in angular [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---) or [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html).

Add into your `addRec()` function for each variable something like this: `console.log(this.yourVariableName)`

and by click on your button your will see the value of your `input` fields in the developer console of your browser.

If you would like to build something like formular, then read the documentation on angulur.io [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).